# Node.js modified AJAX insertion to MongoDB

Tags: ajax, node.js, mongodb

I am succesfully posting an AJAX insert in my MondoDB database.

The user is supposed to fill in 3 fields,

> - Full Name
> - Email
> - Phone

What I would like to do is:

**generate a random number in server-side and save it as a 4th field in my MongoDB.**

Also I would like to post it as a response back to the user.

---

Here is my **users.js file (server-side)**

```
 * POST to adduser.
 */
router.post('/adduser', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var codeResponse = generateCode();
    db.collection('userlist').insert(req.body, function(err, result){
        res.send(
            (err === null) ? { msg: '',code: codeResponse } : { msg: err }
        );
    });
});

function generateCode(){
    var code = Math.random() *1000000;
    code = Math.floor(code);
    return code;
}
```

And this is my **AJAX call(client-side)**

```
    var newUser = {
        'id2': id2,
        'fullname': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputUserFullname').val(),
        'email': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputUserEmail').val(),
        'phone': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputUserPhone').val(),
    }


   $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: newUser,
    url: '/users/adduser',
    dataType: 'JSON'
    }).done(function( response ) {

    // Check for successful (blank) response

    if (response.msg === '') {
         console.log(response);
    }
    else {
        alert('Error: ' + response.msg);
    }
    });
```

Comment: What error or unintended outcome are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy enough, add it to your object before insert and post back the object:

```
router.post('/adduser', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var document = req.body;

    var codeResponse = generateCode();
    document.code = codeResponse;

    db.collection('userlist').insert(document, function(err, result){
        if (err) //do something
            return;
        else
            res.send(document);
    });
});
```